# Cant start, repair ,install windows

Tags: windows

I have a dell inspiron 5559 and i used to have a dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 16.0.4.
After an update of windows 10 i got many problems like my graphic card driver didnt get auto-update and my cpu fan got some problem

After changing my fan windows would enter an automatic repair and before even starting it... it would jump into blue screen and enter a restart loop while my linux would work just fine

I tried installing or repairing windows but before the page for chosing language blue screen apears again and system jumps out of installation

I started a system diagnose and ram memmory test but there wasnt any error.

So i thought maybe its grub menu or linux's problem and i used rm rf root in ubuntu (that was a foolish mistake im really sad about this now) after that still i cant install or repair windows. and when i turn on my pc an error apears
//
Error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mod...
Grub rescue>
//

I tried different windows dvd's for installation all had same problem. And i tried installing or trying ubuntu or kali live using an usb but various errors show up like bootmgr is missing or....

Can anyone help?
Sorry if my text had some english problems :)))

Comment: You'll probably get better responses if you post this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be formatting the entire hard drive then install Windows or Ubuntu would work for you.

Comment: Can do that myslef or i should take it to somewhere?

Comment: If you have a DVD or bootable USB-Drive that contains Windows or Ubuntu, you can do it by yourself: before starting the process of installing any OS, normally you can format the hard drive.